# How to encrypt a USB to be used with MAC & Win

Tags: disk-encryption, operating-systems, usb-drive

I would like to find out if it is possible to encrypt a USB flash drive (or only password protection) which could work with dual OS ( Mac & Windows ).

Is there a free software that i could use to do this or any different method ?

Comment: See http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3067/how-to-protect-data-on-a-thumb-drive?rq=1, if this does not answer your question please edit your question with the additional information.

Comment: i wrote https://github.com/rndme/nadafile to work cross patform w/o drivers or installs to secure contacts on a thumb drive so that i don't dox my friends and family if i lost the drive. It's not whole-disk encryption, but it is cross platform, needing only a browser to run.

Comment: Thank you, i will have a look at it. i think it would serve well.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there is a free software for that, but there is a free trial for [EasyLock](http://www.endpointprotector.com/products/easylock), a cross-platform data encryption software for USB devices. Once you open the product page, select Resources Tab, USB Setup for Windows and Mac. You don't have to install both of them, you just choose the compatible one with the computer where you use it for the 1st time.
If you have any questions, I am here for you.

Comment: veracrypt / bcrypt should also work ? encrypted volumes